# How can i change woo commerce PRODUCT ATTRIBUTES place?

Tags: woocommerce, attributes, product

[image]In the simple product page...I want to move the product attributes to additional information or description tab! how can i do that?

Comment: That's not default WooCommerce, so it must be your theme or a custom plugin putting them there. WooCommerce adds them to the "Additional Information" tab by default

Comment: yes fixed now...the problem is from the theme settings thank you